# Open an X application going through many hoops (SSH, vpn etc)

Tags: vpn, xorg, tunnel, x11-forwarding

### The players:

- my home computer, running Linux with an X server running. (Call it HOME.)
- a remote site, to which I can connect over the internet using a VPN. (SITE)
- a Linux computer at the remote site, to which I can connect with `ssh -X` and nicely have X clients displaying on my local server. (MIDDLE)
- a very old Irix machine (an Onyx) at the remote site, which has no SSH server (therefore I can't `ssh -X` to it), only an `ssh` *client*. (ONYX)

### Purpose

I need to run an X11 application on the ONYX machine, and see the GUI on HOME. I think I stumble upon `xauth` issues. Note that I have tried the obvious: I set DISPLAY to `$ip_address_of_HOME_in_the_SITE_VPN:0`, but the VPN server does not forward connection attempts to its clients, probably for security reasons.

### So far

The current situation is:

- ☑ HOME connects to SITE
- ☑ A vncserver starts on MIDDLE:7
- ☑ vncviewer on HOME connects to vncserver on MIDDLE
- ☑ ONYX starts a forwarding ssh session to MIDDLE:
  `ssh -TfN -L 6007:127.0.0.1:6007 MIDDLE`
- ☒ `DISPLAY=localhost:7 xclient` on ONYX fails with
  **Xlib: connection to "127.0.0.1:7.0" refused by server**

I do know that the forwarding (6007:127.0.0.1:6007) succeeds.

A previous attempt was:

- ☑ HOME connects to SITE
- ☑ HOME connects to MIDDLE:
  `ssh -X MIDDLE` (xclock displays on HOME, DISPLAY is 127.0.0.1:10)
- ☑ ONYX starts an SSH tunnel to MIDDLE:
  `ssh -TfN -L 6010:127.0.0.1:6010 MIDDLE`
- ☒ `DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:10 xclient` fails with
  **X connection to 127.0.0.1:10.0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).**
  while an error pops up in the MIDDLE session:
  **X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.**

### Despair

How can I achieve my purpose?

Comment: I have attempted running `xauth` on ONYX, then `generate 127.0.0.1:10 . trusted` (in the second case above), but I have the same dual error (one on ONYX, one on MIDDLE).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reach a solution using straight SSH tunnels (no -X option), plus some `xauth` fiddling:

- HOME connects to SITE, telnet to ONYX
- HOME ssh tunnel to MIDDLE:
  `ssh -TfN -R 6010:127.0.0.1:6000 MIDDLE`
- ONYX ssh tunnel to MIDDLE:
  `ssh -TfN -L 6010:127.0.0.1:6010 MIDDLE`
- HOME `xauth nextract - $DISPLAY` and copy the output
- ONYX `xauth nmerge -` and paste the previous output
- ONYX `DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:10 xclient` successful :)

Answer (score 0):

[XDMCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_display_manager_%28program_type%29#X_Display_Manager_Control_Protocol). Configure ONYX to accept XDMCP connections, then bring up a SSH tunnel from HOME to MIDDLE. Connect `Xnest` or `Xephyr` to the local end of the SSH tunnel, and log into ONYX.

Comment: I'll try to read more on Xnest and Xephyr, because I don't have experience with these. I am not sure how the tunnel from HOME to MIDDLE should be set up, though. Also, if I configure ONYX to accept XDMCP connections, wouldn't that mean that on the ONYX graphical console I can log on to other systems (i.e the opposite from what I want)?

Comment: Honestly, I don't remember all the details. It's been so long since I've actually had to deal with XDMCP.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the localhost (127.0.0.1) DISPLAY for an X client running on the ONYX box to display on the HOME box.  You need the HOME IP address or hostname.

Comment: -1: You didn't notice the SSH tunnels, I'm afraid. Also, I've already attempted to set DISPLAY to IP_OF_HOME_THRU_VPN_ON_REMOTE_SITE:0, but the VPN server doesn't forward connections *to* the VPN clients, only *from*.

Comment: Actually, I did notice the tunnels.  I saw no reason for their necessity.  Regardless, localhost as the DISPLAY variable for a host without an X server running is incorrect.

Comment: `localhost` in the DISPLAY environment variable implies a TCP/IP connection; no host name at all implies a local UNIX socket. Given that there are many ways to forward TCP/IP sockets to remote machines (e.g. with ssh tunnels, which worked here; see my answer), what do you mean with your last part of your comment, “localhost as the DISPLAY variable for a host without an X server running is incorrect.”? Because reality disproves what you say, so it's incorrect itself.